# PHP/MySQL How to setup an easier SELECT queries?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a search function that lets you input into different type boxes of the last, first and middle names. I don't have any problems with the code, but does anyone know how to optimize it?

The code has multiple if statements that finds out what textbox is unempty and that is then used in the WHERE as you can see below:

```
$where1 = $_POST['firstname'];
            $where2 = $_POST['midname'];
            $where3 = $_POST['lastname'];

            if(!empty($where1) && empty($where2) && empty($where3)){
                $result = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM senior WHERE firstname = '$where1'");
            } else if(!empty($where1) && !empty($where2) && empty($where3)){
                $result = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM senior WHERE firstname = '$where1' AND midname = '$where2'");
            } else if(!empty($where1) && !empty($where2) && !empty($where3)){
                $result = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM senior WHERE firstname = '$where1' AND midname = '$where2' AND lastname = '$where3' ");
            } else if(!empty($where1) && empty($where2) && !empty($where3)){
                $result = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM senior WHERE firstname = '$where1' AND lastname = '$where3' ");
            } else if(empty($where1) && !empty($where2) && !empty($where3)){
                $result = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM senior WHERE lastname = '$where3' AND midname = '$where2' ");
            } else if(empty($where1) && !empty($where2) && empty($where3)){
                $result = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM senior WHERE midname = '$where2'");
            } else if(empty($where1) && empty($where2) && !empty($where3)){
                $result = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM senior WHERE lastname = '$where3'");
            }
```

Comment: You may not want to "simplify" the code.  The multiple queries will allow MySQL to take advantage of indexes specific to each set of conditions.

Comment: Search *"php sql query builder"*. While you're at it, see http://php.net/manual/language.operators.string.php

Comment: This belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @GordonLinoff Please Wait gave a much more simple code though, which I think pretty much the same thing. I think?

Comment: @Phil Thanks for that reference! I need those.

Comment: @EternalHour Sorry, I didn't know that. Saving that link for next time :)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion for you

```
$where = '';
if($where1) $where .= ($where ? " AND " : " ")."firstname = '$where1'";
if($where2) $where .= ($where ? " AND " : " ")."midname = '$where2'";
if($where3) $where .= ($where ? " AND " : " ")."lastname = '$where3'";
$query = "SELECT * FROM senior".($where ? " WHERE ".$where : "");
$result = $connection->query($query);
```

Comment: Instead of all that `$where ?` stuff, why not just fill an array an `implode` on `" AND "`

Comment: Directly copied the code and it didn't work. Going to tweak it a little and see if it will. Thanks for the idea though! Didn't know you can use that for the query.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I encourage you to use [Prepared Statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) in order to improve security among other things.

Related with the code you write above you can try something like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM senior";
$firstcondition = true;

if (!empty($where1))
  addConditon($query, "firstname = ".$where1);
if (!empty($where2))
  addConditon($query, "midname = ".$where2);    
if (!empty($where3))
  addConditon($query, "lastname = ".$where3);

$result = $connection->query($query);

function addCondition($query, $condition) {
  if (!$firstcondition) 
    $query.= " AND ";
  else {
    $firstcondition = false;
    $query.= " WHERE ";
  }
  $query.= $condition;
}
```

Comment: Thank You for both the code and the reference. I've only started learning php two days ago and tutorials online aren't that consistent, and sometimes they're outdated and/or completely different with each other that its hard to understand what's better to use (or to use it at all). :)

Comment: @HopelessNoob I recommend you to read the [Official Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/index.php) and related with the question [Prepared Statements in PHP with PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion: why not use `LIKE`, because it is a search query?

```
$where1 = $_POST['firstname'];
$where2 = $_POST['midname'];
$where3 = $_POST['lastname'];

$result = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM senior WHERE firstname LIKE '%".$where1."%' AND midname LIKE '%".$where2."%' AND lastname LIKE '%".$where3."%' ");
```